# While loop or For loop does not exit

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am trying to create a thread and add it in a list of Threads:

```
int j = 0;
while(j!=6)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(() => SaveImages(L104List[j], folderFilePath, bw));
        ThreadList.Add(th);
        j++;
        //th.Start();
     }
```

but it is not exiting when **j** becomes 6. So it throws a s exception:

> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

BUT, whenever I try to use breakpoints to manually iterate the loop, it exits and goes to the next statements of code. Why is it doing that?

PS. I also tried for loop, and it also does that.

Comment: I guess `L104List` might be less than 6 item in the collection.

Comment: @D-Shih it has a count of 6, so if the j gives 6, it throws and exception because the 6th in the array is 5 as  number right?

Comment: Why not would you use `L104List.Lenght > j` be the condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To start with you will have a *Capture* problem with your *Closure*.
- Your `while` loops seems like the perfect case for a `for` or `foreach` loop
- I am yet to be satisfied that you need to use the `Thread` class for this, or that it will be optimal if you do. Why not use `Task` instead.
- Taking this a step further why not let *TPL* do the hard work for you

Example of easy parallelism

```
Parallel.ForEach(L104List, (item) => SaveImages(item, folderFilePath, bw));
```

The advantages are

- You won't have a closing of the loop variable problem
- You don't have to worry about inefficient thread switching when you overload your cpus
- The task scheduler will divvy out threads from the threadpool in a way that is most likely more efficient than running as many threads as your array holds.
- It will wait until all your work is done
- It's one line of code and easier to understand

Additional notes, if you can make your method async, you can probably gain even more efficiency.

---

[Parallel.ForEach Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Executes a foreach (For Each  in Visual Basic) operation in which
> iterations may run in parallel.

Comment: @TerribleDog You dont, everything will have finished after the execution of the `Parallel.ForEach`

Answer (score 1):

I will do something like this:

```
foreach(var data in L104List)
{
   string local = data;
   ThreadStart work = delegate { SaveImages(local, folderFilePath, bw); };
   new Thread(work).Start();
}
```